# jQuery using current domain dynamically in find() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to search the string `$div` and not select an `a` tag to the domain the script is on. This works, entering the domain statically...

```
        $div.find("a:not([href*=mywebsite])").attr('rel', function(i, val) {
            ...
            return val;
        });
```

But this does not work...

```
        var $this_domain = window.location.hostname;
        // $this_domain.toString();
        $div.find("a:not([href*=" + $this_domain + "])").attr('rel', function(i, val) {
            ...
            return val;
        }
```

Any ideas why this would not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to be impossible for anyone to diagnose without seeing the HTML of the `a` elements you're trying to select, and the value of `$this_domain` (which shouldn't have a `$` prefix as it's a string, not a jQuery object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, `$this_domain` will be a string with at least one `.`, but `.` has a [special meaning](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) in jQuery selectors. You need to [escape the value](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) before finding the elements. Try this:

```
$div.find("a:not([href*=" + $.escapeSelector($this_domain) + "])")
  .attr( ... );
```

Moreover, just to point out, you're not wrapping the value in quotes, which may result in bugs.